# Dependent random variables related by a function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose we have two dependent real valued random variables $X$ and $Y$. Is it true that there exists a function $f$ such that $X = f(Y)$???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: let $Y \sim \text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ and
\begin{align}
(X \mid Y =1) \sim \text{Bernoulli}(3/4)
\\
(X \mid Y =0) \sim \text{Bernoulli}(1/4)
\end{align}
$X$ and $Y$ are clearly dependent, but for each fixed value of $Y$, the random variable $X$ can be either $0$ or $1$, so it is impossible for there to be a function such that $f(Y)=X$.